# How to show child dropdown based on parent dropdown value as default at the time of page update/edit

Tags: yii, yii2

I am using Kartik DepDrop in Yii2. I have a parent dropdown and a child dropdown. When it creates, it works perfect. But at the time of update the form, Parent dropdown's value is selected correctly. But in child dropdown, correct dropdown based on parent dropdown is not showing.

**form.php is:**

```
<?php  echo $form->field($model, 'type')->widget(Select2::classname())->dropDownList(\backend\models\Ratingsbe::getType(), ['id'=>'type-id']); ?>

<?php
  echo $form->field($model, 'relatedid')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
       'options'=>['id'=>'relatedid-id'],
        'type' => 2, //type select2
        'pluginOptions'=>[
        'depends'=>['type-id'],
         'placeholder'=>'Select...',
         'url'=>Url::to(['/ratings/finddata'])
          ],
          ]);
  ?>
```

**controller.php is:**

```
public function actionFinddata()
    {
        $pagegroup = ['Centresbe','Spotinfobe','Sportsbe','Coachesbe','Clinicsbe','Holidaysbe','Eventsbe'];
        $category = '';
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
                $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
                if ($parents != null) {
                    $type = $parents[0];
                    $dynamic_class = '\\backend\\models\\'.$type;
                    if(in_array($type, $pagegroup))
                    {
                          $catres = $dynamic_class::find()->where(['status' => 'Active'] )->one();
                            $category = $catres->category;
                    }
                    
                     $data = $dynamic_class::getdatatype($category);

                    return ['output'=>$data, 'selected'=>''];
                }
            }
            return ['output'=>'', 'selected'=>''];
    }
```

**image output is: **
[image]

relatedid dropdown should be shown based on hotel selected on edit page. Because Hotel is default selected when edit the page.

Comment: Make a function to get `relatedid` on edit. Take query and related code from  `Finddata()` action and make it reusable in both ajax request and normal function call.

Answer (score 0):

This [thread](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/simple-dependent-dropdown/132869/10?u=snathan) in Yii Forum answers your question in a couple of different ways - JavaScript & PHP.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).